# Get JSON in web api and get the specific data from JSON

Tags: json, api, getjson, bitcoin

How can I fetch the json into web api and get the specific data?

For example, this is my web api "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/" and the output is like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "website_slug": "bitcoin", 
        "rank": 1, 
        "circulating_supply": 17145625.0, 
        "total_supply": 17145625.0, 
        "max_supply": 21000000.0, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 6196.07, 
                "volume_24h": 3623440000.0, 
                "market_cap": 106235492694.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": -0.08, 
                "percent_change_24h": -2.9, 
                "percent_change_7d": -6.64
            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1531423345
    }, 
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": 1531423031, 
        "error": null
    }
}
```

I want a code how I can open the "web api link", "get the json into web api", "get the data in json".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what language you are using. It would be helpful to provide that information in the tags or the question itself

If you are using python 3.7

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen 
myjson = JSON.loads(urlopen("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/"))
```

Here you will get the json deserialized into native python nested arrays and dictionaries (dictionaries in your case).

From this you can access elements from the json just like you would any element from a normal python dictionary. For example if I wanted to access the id

```
myjson["data"]["id"]
```

Hope this helped! Best of luck... please reply what language you are using and any frameworks so the community can help you in the best way.